# Google Cast sender iOS app test

Tags: ios, chromecast

I have no receiver device so any other why to testing Cast sender APP.

I have download sample code form Google Cast [Demo app.](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cast-videos-ios/#1)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can check with in simulator also

Comment: Can you suggest me how can test.

Comment: can you show ur tried code it is better to optimize

Comment: but this question is too broad

Comment: Okay, Our main problem is cast button:-  Unavailable: While Cast receivers are not available, the Cast button does not appear

Comment: ya , if you want to stable we can modify,

Comment: in here you need to check with 7 places in cast page delegates